# Yocto: howto disable IO-APIC in a machine.conf file?

Tags: kernel, yocto, cmdline-args

I need to disable IO-APIC kernel option in a new custom-bsp-layer for a machine based on 'meta-intel' of the Yocto 'rocko' branch. To do that I need to add "noapic" option to the Linux kernel cmdline.

I have tested adding different options to `mymachine.conf` file:

```
Option a)
MACHINE_FEATURES += "noapic"

Option b)
APPEND += "noapic"
```

But none is working as expected. When I dump the `core-image-minimal-mymachine.wic` image generated to my USB-pendrive (using `dd`), `grub.cfg` file generated in the EFI partition doesn't include `noapic` option:

```
$ cat efi/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg

default=boot
timeout=5
menuentry 'boot'{
    linux /bzImage root=PARTUUID=b38fcded-b1fa-45bb-a037-cf8648a25e99 rootwait rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0
}
```

How should be fixed this issue? Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: It seems efi/EFI/BOOT/grub.cfg generation is hardcoded into  scripts/lib/wic/canned-wks/mkefidisk.wks. Adding `noapic` at the end of line starting by "bootloader" fixes the issue. However modifying poky repository is not an acceptable solution. How can this script be customized from my custom machine layer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue.

To fix the issue, a file named `mkefidisk.wks` is created inside my custom-bsp-layer directory, replacing the version of this file in the `poky` layer. So, basically, you need to create exactly the same path into your custom bsp layer:

```
custom-bsp-layer/scripts/lib/wic/canned-wks/mkefidisk.wks
```

That file has customized contents:

```
part /boot --source bootimg-efi --sourceparams="loader=grub-efi" --ondisk sda --label msdos --active --align 1024

part / --source rootfs --ondisk sda --fstype=ext4 --label platform --align 1024 --use-uuid

part swap --ondisk sda --size 44 --label swap1 --fstype=swap

bootloader --ptable gpt --timeout=5 --append="rootfstype=ext4 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 noapic"
```

As you can see, 'noapic' option is added at the end of "bootloader" line. After generating my core-image-minimal-mymachine.wic image (again), everything is working as expected! Yeah! xD

More info on this can be found here:

http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#wic-plug-ins-interface

Hope this helps somebody else! :)